# JSONObject serialization using template

Tags: java, json, rest, ognl

i have to build a text from a JSONObject and a Template up. The template seems like this:

```
"Hi ${user.name} ${user.surname}, 

greetings from ${sender.name} with "${message}"
```

The template is not static. i mean, the client can send any type of Entities (from which the JSONObject is unmarshalled) and suitable templates for these.

I would use OGNL on JSONObject navigating over object graph. But are there any other solutions like XSTL for Json? other something like this ?

Comment: Just to be clear, the JSONObject has 'user', 'sender', and 'message' properties?

Comment: yes. but it could be also a complicated data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live with a slightly different syntax for the template, perhaps **mustache** would do it. It is available for multiple languages, including Java and JavaScript. -> http://mustache.github.com/

Comment: i like this. i think it's the answer for the question.
First a few tests, then acceptance ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using org.json's simplistic lib, you could upgrade to a better JSON library (such as [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org)), bind data as regular Maps (Lists, Numbers etc), and then most templating engines could access things as expected.

Or even use full data binding to POJOs with setters, getters, if you need to access data from Java code as well.

Answer (score 0):

*PURE transforms JSON data into HTML*. Works standalone or with dojo, DomAssistant, jQuery,
Mootools, Prototype, Sizzle and Sly

**HTML template**

```
<div class="who">
</div>
```

**JSON Data**

```
{
  "who": "Hello Wrrrld"
}
```

**Run the code**

```
Hello Wrrrld
```

See more info  see  http://beebole.com/pure/